# How can I evaluate $\lim_{x \to \infty} (2^x + 3^x)^{1/x}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

Someone can explain how can I resolve this limit please?

$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} (2^x + 3^x)^{1/x}
$$

I tried to convert to exponential

$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \exp \left(\tfrac{1}{x} \ln(2^{x} + 3^{x})\right)
$$

$$
\exp \left( \lim_{x \to \infty} \tfrac{1}{x}\ln(2^{x} + 3^{x}) \right)
$$

In this part I think applied L'Hospital
$$
\exp \left( \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\ln(2^{x} + 3^{x})}{x} \right)
$$

I noticed that I can't get to  answer

Comment: Seems interesting to me. If you've tried anything yet, post the work here, so that we can analyze your work and can tell you about the mistakes in your method.

Comment: How about taking $ln$ of $\left(2^x + 3^x \right)^{1/x}$

Comment: @user17629 : Please prefer to use \rightarrow instead of -> in TeX !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $x$ be positive. Note that $3^x\le 2^x+3^x\le 2\cdot 3^x$.

Thus
$$3\le (2^x+3^x)^{1/x}\le 3\cdot 2^{1/x}.$$

Since $2^{1/x}\to 1$ as $x\to\infty$, the result follows by **Squeezing**.

**Remark:** Your more complicated method will work, if we use the fact that $\ln(2^x+3^x)=\ln[(3^x)(1+(2/3)^x]=x\ln 3+\ln(1+(2/3)^x)$. Now divide by $x$ and take the limit.

Alternately, one can work with your expression, and evaluate $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln(2^x+3^x)}{x}$ using L'Hospital's Rule.

Comment: This is just the fact that the $p$-norms converge to the max-norm.

Answer (score 3):

$$(2^x+3^x)^{\frac{1}{x}}=3\left(1+\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^x\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}$$

Now 
$$1 \leq \left(1+\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^x\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}
\leq 1+\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^x
$$

So $$\left(1+\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^x\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}\rightarrow 1$$

and 
$$(2^x+3^x)^{\frac{1}{x}}\rightarrow 3$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Factor $3^x$ inside the parenthesis.